# Is the Hessian class SerializerFactory thread-safe?

Tags: java, serialization, thread-safety, hessian

I'd like to use the Hessian (Java) serialization and need to create a `SerializerFactory` with custom serializers (to handle `BigInteger`).  Can I create one of these and share it among threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](http://kickjava.com/src/com/caucho/hessian/io/SerializerFactory.java.htm), then you can notice that SessionFactory stores created serializers in a HashMap, and HashMap is not a thread-safe object. There is an intresting [post](http://lightbody.net/blog/2005/07/hashmapget_can_cause_an_infini.html) about it.

So, the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 2):

It appears this has been fixed for a while now.  They now use ConcurrentHashMap.

http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=1588

04-06-07 15:16   ferg    Fixed in Version     => 3.1.1